# WebDriverException: Message: u'missing ; before statement' ;

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am trying to build a utility function to  output beautiful soup code to a browser I have the following code:

```
def bs4_to_browser(data):

    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(path="F:\FirefoxPortable\Firefox.exe")
    driver.get("about:blank")
    # data = '<h1>test</h1>'  # supposed to come from BeautifulSoup -- this works when uncommented

    driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "{html}";'.format(html=data))
    return

>>> listing
<div class="listingHeader">
....
>>> type(listing)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> a = unicode(listing)
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Now if I run:

```
>>> bs4_to_browser(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/envs/r1/masslist\ml1\views.py", line 606, in bs4_to_browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: ' 
>>> bs4_to_browser(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/envs/r1/masslist\ml1\views.py", line 610, in bs4_to_browser
    driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "{html}";'.format(html=data))
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 401, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'missing ; before statement' ; Stacktrace: 
    at handleEvaluateEvent (about:blank:68:11)
```

How can I fix this?

addendum:

regarding the comments:

1)  WebDriverException: Message: u'syntax error' ; Stacktrace: is produced by the linechange.

2)

```
>>> a = unicode(listing)
>>> a = a.replace('\n', '')
>>> bs4_to_browser(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/envs/r1/masslist\ml1\views.py", line 610, in bs4_to_browser
    driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "{html}";'.format(html=data))
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 401, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'missing ; before statement' ; Stacktrace:
    at handleEvaluateEvent (about:blank:68:11)
>>> a = str(listing)
>>> a = a.replace('\n', '')
>>> bs4_to_browser(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/envs/r1/masslist\ml1\views.py", line 606, in bs4_to_browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: '
>>> bs4_to_browser(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:/envs/r1/masslist\ml1\views.py", line 610, in bs4_to_browser
    driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = "{html}";'.format(html=data))
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 401, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'missing ; before statement' ; Stacktrace:
    at handleEvaluateEvent (about:blank:68:11)
```

3)I'm using FF 31.1 ESR portable and selenium 2.42.1

also I just noticed that if the browser is not completely closed before running  bs4_to_browser you get: "WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: ' "

Comment: Have you tried doing `driver.execute_script('document.body.innerHTML = {};'.format(data))` instead?

Comment: What if you try to replace newlines in a before calling `bs4_to_browser()`, this way: `a = a.replace('\n', '')`. Shot in the dark, but give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I don't really like the first error you've got, which firefox and selenium versions are you using now?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for looking at this , I've tried to answer your comments above - Bill