# How to set the path to a browser executable with python webbrowser

Tags: python, firefox, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I am trying to build a utility function to  output beautiful soup code to a browser I have the following code:

```
def bs4_to_browser(bs4Tag):

    import os
    import webbrowser

    html= str(bs4Tag)

    # html = '<html> ...  generated html string ...</html>'
    path = os.path.abspath('temp.html')
    url = 'file://' + path

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(html)
    webbrowser.open(url)
    return
```

This works great and opens up the HTML in the default browser. However I would like to set the path to a portable firefox executable which is at:

```
F:\FirefoxPortable\firefox.exe
```

I am using win7. How to I set the path to the portable firefox executable?

Comment: I remember you've used selenium for this. Why are you switching to `webbrowser`?

Comment: regarding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736491/webdriverexception-message-umissing-before-statement , thanks for your help on that Alex. I was not able to get it working using selenium perhaps related to firefox browser/webdriver incompatabilities. This seems to be working immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your portable Firefox directly with the url as an argument instead.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["F:\\FirefoxPortable\\firefox.exe", "-new-tab", url])
```

Comment: My only question on this is I would like to open a new tab each time rather than an entire new browser. the webrowser module does appear to allow control of tabs

Comment: List of available [Firefox command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments), should work with -new-tab

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but here a code working with webbrowser and Python 3.11

```
myfirefox = webbrowser.Mozilla("F:\\FirefoxPortableESR\\FirefoxPortable.exe")
myfirefox.open(url)
```

As you will see, it works even if the .exe is not the "real" firefox.