# Opening several tabs in Firefox using Python

Tags: python, firefox

I spend about a minute typing the names of the 10 to 15 sites I usually check first thing in the morning into Firefox. This is a "considerable" waste of my time, so why not automate the process? Having every tab open at the Firefox startup isn't a good solution (because I only check those pages *once*) so I thought a little Python script should do the trick:

```
import webbrowser
with open('url_list.txt', 'r') as url_file:
    for url in url_file:
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

The `url_list.txt` file only has the pages' URLs separated by newlines.

The problem I face is that the behavior of this script depends on whether I have already started Firefox. If Firefox is running, the listed URL's will open in separate tabs, as intended. If Firefox isn't running though, every single URL will open in a single window, which breaks my workflow. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why not just put all your sites into a folder on your bookmarks toolbar, then "Open all in tabs"?

Comment: I dislike that feature, mostly. I have several -personal- issues with Firefox.

Comment: You need this for *nix based systems or any OS?

Comment: I mostly use Windows (which I should have said somewhere...), though any answer that effectively answers this problem is more than welcome.

Comment: I was thinking of using [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), but problem with selenium is that it cannot interact with already opened window. But if you want to use this on system startup then my [this code](https://gist.github.com/ashwch/afc8602c775bd7dac5a4) should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `webbrowser` works in the background consists of creating `subprocess.Popen` objects. This has two underlying effects that map directly with the reported results:

- If Firefox is open, as `webbrowser` detects that Firefox is already running, it sends the correct argument to `Popen`, which results in every URL opening in the current Firefox window.
- If no Firefox process exists, then what happens is that several concurrent requests are being made to Firefox to access the passed URLs. As no window exists, there isn't a way to create tabs and the last option Firefox has is to present every link in a separate window.

I managed to solve this problem by simply joining all URL's while calling Firefox. This has certain limitations though (referent to the character limit of a command string) but it is a very simple and efficient solution:

```
import subprocess
firefox_path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
cmdline = [firefox_path]
with open('url_list.txt', 'r') as url_file:
    for url in url_file:
        cmdline.append(url)
subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
```

Comment: OK, I suppose, as long as one doesn't mind hardcoding the path to the Firefox executable (and assuming it's the default browser).

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it without hard-coding the browser path is to open the first one, wait a few seconds, and then open the rest:

```
import webbrowser, time
with open('url_list.txt', 'r') as url_file:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in url_file]
webbrowser.open(urls[0])
time.sleep(4)
for url in urls[1:]:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\geckodriver.exe")
binary = FirefoxBinary('usr/bin/firefox') # Optional
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary) # Optional
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer

Comment: The above code is launch the URL in FireFox browser, Then Open a new tab use the below code -
    pyautogui.press('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press('t')

Comment: OK, you might want to edit your answer to make it more useful for other users of SO